# url rewrite is not working

Tags: .htaccess

htaccess on xammp (windows)

I can't get my .htaccess run on my localhost. I want to make a url rewrite which makes

**http://localhost/mywebsite/about.php** to **http://localhost/mywebsite/about**

Here's my .htaccess and I've put it in inside the C:\xampp\htdocs. BTW my website is located in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

I already done
**"LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"**
in **C:\xampp\apache\conf\http.conf** but still no luck.

I'm pretty sure my mod_rewrite is already working but I'm not sure about my .htaccess

Can anyone can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Almost. You have 2 conditions:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

which checks if the request maps to a *non*-existing directory and:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

wchich checks if the request maps to *an existing file*. You want to make the second check to see if it maps to an existing file *if it ended with* **.php**. So you want to change your second condition to:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```